# Drawing Rectangle as a Textboxes border

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this class Validators, where I validate all the textboxes in my WinForms Project. What I don't know how to do is : "I can't change the bordercolor of the textboxes that failed to validate". So I used this `LoginForm_Paint` Event in the same class "Validators". I don't know how to use it, maybe it shouldn't be there in the first place, maybe I don't know how to use it. Can someone help me please ?

```
public void LoginForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
    Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
}

public bool ValidateTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I wanted to use it like this (like in the LoginForm) :

```
public void LoginForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
    Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
}

public bool ValidateTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, textBox.Location.X,
                          textBox.Location.Y, textBox.Width, textBox.Height);

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work that way. It doesn't recognize the instance I created `Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;`.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work that way"? any specific error message?

Comment: It just doesn't recognize the instance I created "Graphics graphics = e.Graphics".
I edited the question.

Comment: You cannot store the e.Graphics object you get in the Paint event and use it later.  It is disposed after the Paint event stops running.  Re-drawing the border of controls is just a bad idea.  Consider using the BackColor instead.

Comment: I tried using the BackColor, but I don't like it that way. It also looks horrible. I imagine presenting this project in my university like this. I would fail my students if they did it like that. Hahah xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `graphics` is not "recognized" since it is defined outside of the method you are using it in, i.e defined locally in `LoginForm_Paint` and used in `ValidateTextBoxes`.

You should use the graphics object of the TextBox you are painting on:

```
public bool ValidateTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            Graphics graphics = textBox.CreateGraphics();
            graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, textBox.Location.X,
                          textBox.Location.Y, textBox.Width, textBox.Height);

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```